# Is there a name for thin (3/8") redwood/cedar boards for basketweave?

Tags: fence, lumber

I have to replace a "basketweave" style fence section on my property.  The horizontal fence boards in the existing fence sections are 3/8" thick redwood boards (approximately 4" high, 3/8" thick, 8' long).  The thin boards are easy to weave in and out of the pickets, resulting in an opaque fence with a lovely basketweave effect.

[image: example backetweave boards]

I've tried all the lumber stores nearby (San Francisco Bay Area, north Peninsula) and nobody seems to have heard of anything like these.  I suspect this is a classic case of my not knowing exactly what I'm asking for.  I know I could produce them by ripping Redwood 2x4s, but the prospect of ripping down 100 or more of these on my poor little table saw just isn't very inviting.

Anyone know what this kind of board is called?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Shopping questions are OT per our [faq] so I removed that part of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called bender board. Typically made of Redwood for rot resistance.

It is used as edging for gardening and lawns, forms for concrete walkways and base material for making lattice.

Available on the US West Coast either direct from Redwood products mills or from Lowe's or Home Depot in thicknesses from 1/4" to 3/8"

Comment: 4" nominal bender board should be readily available. If the picture is of the actual installation and not simply to illustrate the basket weave technique, the boards are more like 8" nominal, compare to the adjacent CMU wall that would typically be of 8" high blocks. This material may not be as easy to find.

Comment: Yes, the days of indiscriminate Redwood harvest are over. There are specialty Redwood suppliers and they would be the best bet for obtaining the product. If you have a local lumberyard that supplies 2" x 12" Redwood planks, they might be able to order it direct for you.